# Bash - Literal Grep With User Input

Tags: bash, grep

I'm writing a script that has to discern between .tar, .gz, and .tar.gz file formats from user input. 
e.g. (scriptname /path/to/file.tar.gz)

If tried to pass  it through something like this (with variables stated at the top), but all three statements for tar gz and tar.gz pick up a tar.gz file.

```
echo "$1" | grep -q "$gz"
if [ $? -eq 0 ];then
  echo "found"
else
  echo "not found"
fi
```

How would I go about isolating it to a singular file format? 
I've tried fgrep and grep -F.

Comment: `grep -q "$gz"` would evaluate to `grep -q ""`, matching the empty string,
unless you declare $gz somewhere?

Comment: Yes i believe i stated that i stated the variables at the top.

Comment: Aha. Well, it's unclear which variables you meant. I surmise that you repeat that code 3 times, each time with a different value for the single variable $gz? In that case, your ordering is off: `.gz` will match `.tar.gz`, so put that one last.

Comment: I was originally stating the variable as gz=.tar.gz , gzc=.gz , tar=.tar and having it run through every option until a match is found. The problem is that it literally matched all three.

Comment: Yes, all 3 of those would match a .tar.gz. Also remember that `.` in grep and regular expressions means 'any character', so `.gz` would also match 'Xgz'. And it would also match `"foogz.bar"`, so add a `$` to match end-of-line. Mat's answer below is the way to go, but I just wanted to show that your approach can work if you order them properly: `"\.tar\.gz$"`, `"\.tar$"`, `"\.gz$"`. Also, some people use `".tgz"` ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use a case statement for this:

```
case "$1" in
  *.tar.gz) echo "tar gz" ;;
  *.tar)    echo "plain tar" ;;
  *.gz)     echo "plain gz" ;;
  *)        echo "oups." ;;
esac
```

Comment: Thanks, I had thought about using case but couldn't see how it applied!

Comment: @Revolt - just to make sure you understand: this will categorize file name extensions, not file formats (what you had you asked for). UNIX tools don't use or care about file name extensions so just because a file name ends in ".gz" doesn't mean it's a gzipped file, it could just as easily be a tar file or a postscript file or a plain text file. To find the file format you'd need to use the `file` command or similar.